# Error al integrar Stripe en Angular "TypeError: http.Agent is not a constructor"

Tags: nodejs, angular, stripe

Estoy intentando integrar Stripe en mi aplicacion de angular pero obtengo un error en tiempo de ejecución, el error es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: http.Agent is not a constructor
    at Object../node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js
```

He actualizado mi versión de Node a la de la 6 a la 12 y aún así me aparece el error.

Mi componente es el siguiente

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_51H10XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
});

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'StripeProject';

  constructor()
  {
    console.log(this.title);
  }


}
```

El error salta de la linea

```
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_51H10XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
});
```

Como ven es solo la configuración inicial y en cuanto sirvo la aplicacion el error del inicio salta a consola. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida! Gracias!

Comment: no uses el keyword `new` al parecer `Stripe` no es un contructor por eso te da error.

Comment: Hola! ya lo hice y sigue marcando el mismo error. El detalle es que la funcion "new Stripe" utiliza dentro de sus dependencias la funcion "new http.Agent" la cual es la que esta directamente marcando el error. Ahora bien, ya quite la palabra "new" y marca el mismo error.

Comment: Qué versión de stripe-node estás utilizando en tus dependencias? Se soluciona si utilizas la última versión, 8.68.0?

Comment: Según mi archivo package.json tengo "stripe": "^8.68.0"

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Creo que en este caso debes usar Stripe.js, la cual es la librería de Stripe para el frontend. stripe-node es únicamente para el backend, lo cual podría llevar a este error. Intenta cambiar tus dependencias de stripe-node a stripe-js (`^1.7.0`).

Comment: Dos cosas más; 1. tu `sk_test_` está editada en el segundo ejemplo, pero está completa en el primero. 2. En el frontend, debes utilizar tu llave pública, e.g. `pk_test_....`

Comment: Gracias por el dato, ya hice el cambio. Probaré lo que me comentas de stripe.js, existirá paquete npm para esa versión? O tengo que asumir que mis referencias a stripe serán todas de lado del cliente?

Comment: Claro, hay un paquete npm: `npm install @stripe/stripe-js` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo mi propia pregunta, espero ayude a alguien más.

Las funciones Node no funcionan en Angular por el simple hecho que Angular es un lenguaje de cliente. Por lo que se deberá crear un API ya sea en Node, PHP, C# o en cualquier otro lenguaje de lado del servidor que sea consumido por la App de Angular y compatible con Stripe. Si no se desea crear una API en otro lenguaje o hacer configuraciones extra, se puede hacer con Firebase Cloud Functions, pero al parecer es necesario tener cuenta de pago para realizar las pruebas.

Asi que:

1. No es posible crear en Angular una app que consuma los servicios de Stripe.
2. Crear un API que sea consumido por la app de Angular.

Y bueno, lo coloco para que no pierdan el tiempo.